# Using ioctl(), read() and malloc() to receive a message from server not working properly

Tags: c, sockets, client

I am trying to make a simple server client program in C. On the client I try to receive the message from the server, but the size of the message is not predetermined. Therefore, I want to check how many bytes are coming in, and `malloc` the appropriate size.

I tried to use `ioctl` but it seems like it gets the info I want too late. 
This is what I have.

```
char *message_from_server;
int length;
while(1){
    ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &length);
    message_from_server = malloc(length);
    read(socket, message_from_server, length);
}
```

The first time I use it, `length` is 0. The second time, length is equal to that of the first message. If I put the line `ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &length);` after i read, that might give me trouble with mallocing the correct amount of space. Is this even a valid way to solve my problem?

I have heard that one can use `realloc` to solve my problem, but I am struggling to see how to it so solve my problem. If that is a better way to do it, I would be happy for any tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Well with TCP only, the size of incoming data IS predetermined.  It will be one byte or something larger.  If you are trying to implement application messages longer than one bye by 'peeking' with ioctl, or assuming that read() will always load your buffer with complete messages longer than one byte, you will soon be in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) allows you to increase the size of a memory block, preserving its content.

So, in your case:

1. read size of incoming packet
2. update memory block to store packet, preserving what have been read previously
3. read the packet
4. goto 1. or exit

Your code should look like:

```
/* memory to store message, initially, no memory */
char *message_from_server = NULL;
/* size of memory */
int total_length = 0;

/* sizeof incoming packet*/
int packet_lentgh;

/* position to write in memory */
int offset;

while(1){
    /* read size of incoming packet*/
    ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &packet_lentgh);

    if (0 != packet_lentgh)
    {
        /* something is ready to be read on socket */

        /* update memory size */
        total_length += packet_lentgh;

        /* allocate much memory*/
        message_from_server = realloc(message_from_server, total_length);
        if (NULL == message_from_server)
        {
            perror("realloc");
            abort();
        }

        /* compute the position to write in memory */
        offset = total_length - packet_lentgh;

        /* read the packet */
        read(socket, message_from_server + offset, packet_lentgh);
    }
    else
    {
        /* nothing to read 
           wait for packet or stop loop... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Thank you!